# How to create the matrix for chord diagram based on coloumn value:

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, chord-diagram

Say I have a data-frame which has data in the following format.

```
UID | Name | ID
----------------
1 | ABC | IM-1
2 | XYZ | IM-2
3 | XYZ | IM-2
4 | PQR | IM-3
5 | PQR | IM-4
6 | PQR | IM-5
7 | XYZ | IM-5
8 | ABC | IM-5
```

I need to create a matrix that feeds into the chord diagram code. that requires the output in the following format:

```
(array([[0,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,0],
        [1,1,0,2]]),['ABC','XYZ','PQR'])
```

Note: In this example, 
- the "Name" is finite in the list (i.e. ABC, XYZ or PQR)
- "ID" is shared between records
- the fourth column is the number of records that stand alone (for example ABC is part of a single record *IM-1* and PQR appears twice in *IM-4* and *IM-5*
- the other members of the matrix are the linkages between Names based on ID (for example *IM-5*, increases the value of *PQR-XYZ*, *XYZ-PQR*, *PQR-ABC*,*ABC-PQR*,*XYZ-ABC* & *ABC-XYZ*)
- the goal is to create a chord diagram for the connections between the "Name" field

I know this is quite a read. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is unclear to me how you arrive at the adjacency matrix in your example. Why does the array have 4 columns if you have 3 names? And why does it sum to 10 if you have only 8 entries in your table?

Comment: The adjacent matrix can be returned as the names for the matrix, in this case, the rows and columns are the order ABC,XYZ,PQR.

The 4th column contains the number of records that are not linked to any other name. For example, for ID "IM-1" there is only one record "ABC", similarly for IM-3 and IM-4 PQR is not connected to any other name hence in 3x4 there is 2.

The number of entries depends on the links for IM-5, the links that are created are PQR-XYZ, XYZ-PQR, PQR-ABC,ABC-PQR,XYZ-ABC & ABC-XYZ where we can see that XYZ-PQR, ABC-PQR & ABC-XYZ can be confused as duplicates but is required

Comment: Thank you, that is much clearer. I updated my answer, and included a function to get the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer but the approach is basically the same. Parse the data into a data frame, do an [inner join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) on `ID` to get the pairs of names that are linked by sharing a common `ID`. Then convert this edge list into an adjacency matrix. Finally some faffing around to get the "dangling" edges, i.e. the `ID` with only a single occurrence (added in the updated answer), and group their counts by the corresponding `Name`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Create adjacency matrix from a dataframe, where edges are implicitly defined by shared attributes.

Answer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849602/how-to-create-the-matrix-for-chord-diagram-based-on-coloumn-value
"""
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

def parse_data_format(file_path):
    # read data skipping second line
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='|', skiprows=[1])

    # strip whitespace from column names
    df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())

    # strip whitespace from values
    df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
    df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

    return df


def get_edges(df):
    """Get all combinations of 'Name' that share a 'ID' value (using an inner join)."""
    inner_self_join = df.merge(df, how='inner', on='ID')
    excluding_self_pairs = inner_self_join[inner_self_join['UID_x']!=inner_self_join['UID_y']]
    edges = excluding_self_pairs[['Name_x', 'Name_y']].values
    return edges


def get_adjacency(edges):
    "Convert a list of 2-tuples specifying source and target of a connection into an adjacency matrix."
    order = np.unique(edges)
    total_names = len(order)
    name_to_idx = dict(list(zip(order, range(total_names))))
    adjacency = np.zeros((total_names, total_names))
    for (source, target) in edges:
        adjacency[name_to_idx[source], name_to_idx[target]] += 1
    return adjacency, order


def get_dangling_edge_counts(df):
    # get IDs with count 1
    counts = Counter(df['ID'].values)
    singles = [ID for (ID, count) in counts.items() if count == 1]
    # get corresponding names
    names = [df[df['ID']==ID]['Name'].values[0] for ID in singles]
    # convert into counts
    return Counter(names)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # here we read in the data as a file buffer;
    # however, normally we would hand a file path to parse_data_format instead
    import sys
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    else:
        from io import StringIO

    data = StringIO(
        """UID | Name | ID
        ----------------
        1 | ABC | IM-1
        2 | XYZ | IM-2
        3 | XYZ | IM-2
        4 | PQR | IM-3
        5 | PQR | IM-4
        6 | PQR | IM-5
        7 | XYZ | IM-5
        8 | ABC | IM-5
        """
    )

    df = parse_data_format(data)
    edges = get_edges(df)
    adjacency, order = get_adjacency(edges)
    print(adjacency)
    # [[0. 1. 1.]
    #  [1. 0. 1.]
    #  [1. 1. 0.]]
    print(order)
    # ['ABC' 'PQR' 'XYZ']

    dangling_edge_counts = get_dangling_edge_counts(df)
    print(dangling_edge_counts)
    # Counter({'PQR': 2, 'ABC': 1})

    last_column = np.zeros_like(order, dtype=np.int)
    for ii, name in enumerate(order):
        if name in dangling_edge_counts:
            last_column[ii] = dangling_edge_counts[name]
    combined = np.concatenate([adjacency, last_column[:, np.newaxis]], axis=-1)
    print(combined)
    #[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
    # [1. 0. 1. 2.]
    # [1. 1. 2. 0.]]
```

Comment: Happy to help. If it works for you, could you please accept the answer then?